# RoR: should daemons located in /lib should know the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm planning to create a daemon in my rails application that looks every 10 minutes for specific mongodb records and create a new mongodb record based on the query results. 
I think the daemon should be located in the "lib", but I'm not sure the lib components should "know" my model classes.
What do you think? Am I missing the role of the lib? Do you have a suggestion for other implementation?

What about just scheduling the task in a deamon located in /lib? Example:

```
# file: app/models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.run!
    # do something
  end
end

# file: lib/my_daemon.rb
class MyDaemon
  def self.start!
    loop do
      MyModel.run!
    end

    sleep(1000)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want any task to run within the context of your application, I would recommand you use a rake task. That means the task will go your `lib/project.rake` file.

To get this run at regular intervals, you have a bunch of options, one is setting up a cron job to run it. You can even use a gem using cron to command its execution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. What about the daemon knowing the model? Do you think it's a right way to achieve it?

Comment: I think that any modification that could impact your models coherence and such should be created in the context of the app, to be safe. You could create mongodb queries (without mongoid) to go faster, but it's a risky business if you don't know what you are doing. Moreover these tasks need integration tests as well, so it should be easier to write these in the app context.

Comment: What about just schedule those tasks in the lib/daemon.rb. I'm editing my original question to add an example of what I mean.